# Cubic textures and pixel formats in Ogre3D

Tags: textures, ogre, pixelformat, cubic

In the Ogre material file, the cubic texture is defined as:

```
cubic_texture <front> <back> <left> <right> <up> <down> separateUV
```

Does this mean that it's impossible to set the pixel format as is the case with normal textures?

```
texture <texturename> [<type>] [unlimited | numMipMaps] [alpha] [<PixelFormat>] [gamma]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `texture <texturename> [<type>] [unlimited | numMipMaps] [alpha] [<PixelFormat>] [gamma]` and set `type` to `cubic`. Then you can still modify `<PixelFormat>`.